# Working with peak current of mosfet

Tags: transistors, high-current

In the datasheet, the transistor has two max current values, in the case of the IRF510

```
Continuous Drain Current = 5.6A
Pulsed Drain Current a IDM = 20A
```

with a pulse width of `20uS`

Which is the assumed  duty cycle for this values? Ts = 40uS and D = 50%?

Which current value should I consider if I want to work with a different duty cycle? 80% for example.

Comment: Note that those 'max current values' are _absolute maxium_ ratings, not normal operating currents. The data sheet says: 'CAUTION: Stresses above those listed in “Absolute Maximum Ratings” may cause permanent damage to the device. **This is a stress only rating** and operation of the device at these or any other conditions above those indicated in the operational sections of this specification is not implied.'

Comment: @BruceAbbott In this particular case the absolute maximum ratings are the same as the peak operating ratings (at least the parameters in the OP).

Comment: @user57709 No, they are **stress** ratings, not operating ratings. _Operating_ an IRF510 at 20A peak or 5.6A continuous will seriously impact its reliability.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The datasheet has the same values (for these two parameters) under "Absolute Maximum Ratings" and under "Specifications".  There is usually a difference in these values, but not for this device.

Comment: If its not explicit in the datasheet, then you should limit your duty cycle such that the average of the 'pulsed' current doesn't exceed the 'continuous' rating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the notes underneath that part of the datasheet:

> Notes
>   a. Repetitive rating; pulse width limited by maximum junction temperature (see fig. 11).

Fig. 11:

[image: Fig. 11 - Maximum Effective Transient Thermal impedance, Junction-to-Case]

From this, you can see that for 80% duty cycle (Duty factor, D = 0.8) we are beyond the scope of the graph (it only covers D <= 0.5). For that reason, you will need to work within the continuous rated current of the device.

For duty cycles <= 50%, you can read off the transient thermal impedance reduction for short pulses & low duty cycle, add in the impact of the case-to-ambient conditions and then ensure that the junction temperature stays below the absolute maximum rating for your power dissipation.

That said, I would just work well within the continuous current rating of the device and in fact overrate it by a significant margin to ensure that the circuit you design is robust in a wide variety of conditions.

Comment: There is a curve on this figure for different values of duty cycle.  There isn't a curve for a value of 0.8, so one can't be assumed.  This value would appear to be outside the scope of a repetitive pulse (in this context) and so the continuous ratings should be used (as you point out).

Comment: You're quite right - I misread to 0-0.50 curve label. Will update the answer appropriately.

Comment: In addition 5.6A is the ideal value with Case temperature = 25C. Depending on the cooling conditions you need to further derate `http://www.vishay.com/docs/91015/sihf510.pdf` Fig 9